# Scala: overriding String's hashCode for a test

Tags: string, scala, testing

I have a function that I would like to test that does a hash on a string and then mods the hash, and uses the result in a particular way.  I would like to write tests for this method using strings that have particular hash codes.  My first attempt to get this to work was to override the hashCode method in the string:

```
val testString = new String("test") { override def hashCode() = 3 }
// use testString as input to the method I want to test
```

This would have worked great, except `String` is final, so it doesn't compile (`illegal inheritance from final class String`).

So my question is, is there another way to do this?  These are the options I can think of:

1. Just pick some strings, put their (default) hash codes in a comment in the test, and use those.
2. Change the interface to the method (which currently is `def useHash(s: String): Int`) to something that will let me provide a string with an overriden hash code some how, by making a new type that is related to `String`.
3. (Maybe this is the same as (2)) Use some kind of implicit conversion in the implementation code, or take as a second argument a function that computes the hash (defaulting to just calling `s.hashCode`).

My inclination is to use method (1).  I don't really want to make the implementation code more complex just so that I can test it in a slightly more fancy way.  But I wondered if there was some way of using scala foo that I don't know of that would let me easily specify particular hash codes in my test without complicating my implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the TypeClass pattern. Eg:

```
trait Hasher[T] {
  def hash(t: T): Int
}

object Hasher {
  implicit val stringHasher = new Hasher[String] {
    val mySpecialStrings = List("ein" -> 123123, "schwein" -> 432121, "dry" -> 948912).toMap
    def hash(str: String) = mySpecialStrings.getOrElse(str, str.hashCode)
  }
}

object MyStuff {
  def methodUsingHasher[T](t: T)(implicit hasher: Hasher[T]) = ??? // do stuff
}
```